# installing material-react-table breaks my React JS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to use material-react-table in my React JS app...

These are the dependencies that I already have and I have been using in my components:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.22.1",
        "@azure/msal-react": "^1.3.1",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.0",
        "@mui/material": "^5.14.0",
        "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.6.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1123.0",
        "axios": "^0.26.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
        "html-entities": "^2.3.3",
        "material-react-table": "^1.14.0",
        "material-table": "^1.69.3",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.28.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "util": "^0.12.4",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    }
```

I am using npm and run this command:

```
npm install material-react-table @mui/material @mui/icons-material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

After it has completed I am getting  "compiled with problems"

many of the messages read:

```
export 'default' (imported as 'TableRow') was not found in '@mui/material/TableRow' (module has no exports)
export 'default' (imported as 'TableCell') was not found in '@mui/material/TableCell' (module has no exports)
export 'default' (imported as 'Typography') was not found in '../Typography' (module has no exports)
\\etc...
```

I have changed nothing in my code except for installing the package. I have also tried installing just the material-react-table itself w/o the dependences but I am still facing the same problem.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks for looking.

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules`  and reinstalling it.

Comment: @geeky01adarsh that seemed to have worked! I will continue to test and check! Thanks for that suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such errors usually occur when `node_modules` haven't been installed properly. Deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling it, might fix your issue.